# Moving code to an exported function results in TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I am using `express` and `mysql` packages to just test out queries.

I had this code:

```
connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    connection.end();
    console.log('error');
    throw error;
  }
  connection.end();
  console.log(results);
  return results;
});
```

And it works just fine. But when I move it to a different file and try to export it like this:

`query.js`

```
const connection = require('../config/connection');

connection.connect();

module.exports = async (query) => connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
  console.log(query);
  if (error) {
    // connection.end();
    console.log('error');
    throw error;
  }
  // connection.end();
  console.log(results);
  return results;
});
```

`app.js`

```
try {
  const queryResult = await query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution');
  console.log(queryResult, 2);
  res.send(queryResult);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at stringify (C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\tatooify\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1119:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\tatooify\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\tatooify\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at app.get (C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\tatooify\server\app.js:44:9)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Also in console logs I get, a big object followed by number 2, then I get the errthe ``or, then I get the query value, and then the result. Like so:

```
Big object 2

error

SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution

[ RowDataPacket { solution: 2 } ]
```

So what this tells me is that my code runs in async. Removing async/await from both files doesn't change anything. So my code first runs the `app.js` code, then the `query.js` code, which takes some time. But why? And how can I make it wait? `connection.query()` does ***not*** return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your `async` function does not wait for query to finish.

It should return a promise that resolves when the query completes, but instead returns promise that immediately resolves into return value of function `connection.query()`.

You should change that to:

```
module.exports = (query) => {

    return new Promise(resolve => 
        connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
          console.log(query);
          if (error) {
            // connection.end();
            console.log('error');
            throw error;
          }
          // connection.end();
          console.log(results);
          resolve(results);
        })
    );

}
```

With omited commented lines and shorter syntax:

```
module.exports = (query) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
  connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
    if (error) return reject(error);

    resolve(results);
  })
);
```

And even shorter:

```
module.exports = (query) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    connection.query(query, (error, results) => 
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(results)
  )
);
```

**To clarify**: your `async` keyword did not have any effect, because what it does is allow you to use await in its function and wraps whatever you return into a promise.

You did not use any `await`s and immediately returned result via lambda function.

Note that your return statement returned from callback passed to connection.query function and not from the main function.